# Fragment layout limitation using Scrollview and tablelayout

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I am a beginner in android dev, and I struggle with the following. 
I would like to create a Fragment with a tablelayout created programmatically.
I first started in a Activity instead of a fragment I did that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_testtable, null,false);
    fillLayout(view);       
    setContentView(view);
}

protected void fillLayout(View rootView) {

    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow    tr;
    TextView    tv;
    int i = 0;  

    tl = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.time_range);

    for (i = 0 ; i < 10  ; i++ ) { 
        tv = new CellWorkshopTable(this);
        tv.setText("11h00 - 14h40" );
        tr = new TableRow (this);
        tr.addView(tv);    
        tl.addView(tr); 
    }

    [...]

}
```

It worked well, table was created as I wanted with scrolling in 2 axis etc etc. Then I wanted to set this into a fragment, so I did the following in my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View aView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_testtable, container, false);   
    fillLayout(aView);  
    return aView;
}
```

And so nothing appears when I commit the fragment, No errors in logcat, no crash, seems that everything is there but nothing is displayed.

Here is the layout, the purpose is to have the complete structure, and just add the tableRow and cells (which are textviews):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/time_table"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_range"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </TableLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dp" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_rooms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/time_table_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So When writing this question **I tried to simplify the layout by removing HorizontalScrollView and his childs, and then TableRows added in the first tablelayout are then displayed**

removing HorizontalScrollView but keeping TableLayout+id/header_rooms and TableLayout+id/time_table_content, make header_rooms working and time_table_content KO.

So do fragments have a layout number limitation, and how can I circonvent this?

Answer (score 0):

In fact by cleaning up all the unnecessary element in my layout, it then works as intented.

So fragment seems to be more "strict" about layout element combination.